# How to simulate touch scrolling (drag) in a div using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know how we can do it with JavaScript but can we indicate in CSS in a specific `div` that all mouse events have to behave like touch events or some scroll property to handle the scroll interaction?

This is the JavaScript solution I want to replicate with CSS only.

```js
(function(){
  var curYPos, curXPos, curDown;
  const $div = document.querySelector('#main')
  
  $div.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ 
    if(curDown){
      window.scrollBy(curXPos - e.pageX, curYPos - e.pageY);
    }
  });

  $div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){ 
    curYPos = e.pageY; 
    curXPos = e.pageX; 
    curDown = true; 
  });

  $div.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){ 
    curDown = false; 
  });
})()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 200;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: segoe ui, helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Defaults */
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p, a, span {
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #666;
  liine-height: 20px;
}

#main {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ede5ff;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 540px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

/* Header */
header {
  padding: 120px 0px 120px 0px;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 220%;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
}

header p {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Section */
.section {
  padding: 40px 0px 40px 0px;
}

.section.dark {
  background: #dedede;
}

.section h2 {
  color: #444;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Code */
.code {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #dedede;
  color: #666;
}

.section.dark .code {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <header>
    <h1>Click and drag to scroll!</h1>
    <p class="belowHeader">(The Javascript way)</p>
  </header>

  <div class="section dark">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h2>Setting our variables</h2>
      <div class="code">
        var curXPos = 0, curYPos = 0, curDown = false;
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h2>Mouse down event</h2>
      <div class="code"> window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){ curDown = true; curYPos = e.pageY; curXPos = e.pageX; });
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section dark">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h2>Mouse up event</h2>
      <div class="code">
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){ curDown = false; });
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h2>Mouse move event</h2>
      <div class="code">
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ 
    if(curDown === true){
      window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollLeft + (curXPos - e.pageX), document.body.scrollTop + (curYPos - e.pageY));
    }
  });
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: because I couldn't find any CSS solution I tried to overwrite mouse events with touch events in specific divs but it doesn't work.

Any idea or JS shorthand solution will be really appreciate!